# Facebook Application/page tab Login iframe issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

I have a Facebook app which requires users to log in using Facebook to post to the app, my issue is that if the user is new i.e. has not given permission to the app to use the log in they are led to a blank page when looking at the app in the page tab iframe.

So basically new user finds my fan page, click on the iframe tab to see the app, clicks log in using Facebook and the page that loads in the iframe tab is blank.  Everything works fine when people find the site organically it only fails within the loaded iframe tab.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Does your server correct auto response from Facebook including the access token etc?